# CKEditor returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, ckeditor

I've turned on CKEditor to my textarea. Every time, when I try to proceed typed text in it, CKEditor returns [object Object] instead of any content.
What should I do and what could I missed?  Please, help to noob

Used `$('#area-answer').val(CKEDITOR.instances["area-answer"].getData())` construction

Comment: well, although all of these users gave me good advices, i've found right solution by myself. maybe it's not so good waybut it works in my case. i've made a function that get ckeditor data and set it for default textarea. then, it proceeds in ajax as usual

Comment: function submition() {
   var areaText = CKEDITOR.instances['area-answer'].getData();
document.getElementById('area-answer').value = areaText;
var textval = document.getElementById('area-answer').value;

Answer (score 1):

### Get value of CK-Editor

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    CKEDITOR.replace('area');
    
});

function submition() {
   var areaText = CKEDITOR.instances['area'].getData();
    alert(areaText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://openconcept.ca/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kevee/quail/master/examples/common/style.css">
 
 
<form  method="post">
    <!-- same strings-->
    <textarea id="area" ></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="submition();" />
</form>
```

Comment: alert shows that right content returnes. but i've got div, not form. how can i use it with div?

Comment: wow, alert shows, but on the page i still see [object Object]

Comment: what u got while alert(CKEDITOR.instances["area-answer"].getData()) 
try console.log(CKEDITOR.instances["area-answer"].getData())

Answer (score 0):

try to use html() instead of use val();

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, still [object Object]'s returnes

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<textarea id="my-editor">
<input id="send" type="button" value="Send">
```

JS for CKEditor

```
$('#send').click(function() {
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['DOM-ID-HERE'].getData()
    // send your ajax request with value
    // profit!
});
```